# How to wait indefinitely till the page loads in javascript test case

Tags: javascript, selenium, monitoring, newrelic

I have a javascript performance monitoring synthetic script.I want to know if i can apply a statement to wait for the page to load since it has lot of redirection and takes time.

Currently using ...

```
$browser.sleep(80000);
```

I want to replace it with indefinite wait till page loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can check/wait indefinitely until the page gets loaded with the help of JavaScript's `window.onload`.

Try the below code which will check every 2 seconds and waits until the page gets loaded. Once the page is loaded then the loop will break otherwise it will run indefinitely :

```
var status = false;
window.sleep = function() { 
    return setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("=> Waited for 2 seconds...");
    }, 2000);
}
var getStatus = function() {
    for(var i = 0;; i++) {
        if(window.onload = function() {
            return true;
            }) {
            status = true;
            console.log(i+"). Loaded ? "+status);
            break;
        } else {
            console.log(i+"). Loaded ? "+status);
            sleep();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
getStatus();
```

`getStatus()` will returns true once the page gets loaded successfully otherwise it won't return anything until the page gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use clearTimeout() for this.

```
function timeOutFunction() {
  myTimeOut = setTimeout(function()
    { 
     $browser.sleep() }, 80000);
    }

function stopTimeOutFunction() 
    {
      clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    }
```

stopTimeOutFunction will overwrite functionality of timeOutFunction function, thus preventing timeout.